# Error Couldn't find a `pages` directory. Please create one under the project root"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Previously my project setup was

```
public
.next
src
   pages
   components
   assets
next.config.js
```

This was working fine but I changed the structure to following

```
public
src
   client
    next.config.js
    jsconfig.json
    pages
    components
    assets
   server
    index.js
```

now this one is not working. I am getting error `Couldn't find a`pages`directory. Please create one under the project root`

Here is my updated next.config.js

```
const withPlugins = require("next-compose-plugins");
const optimizedImages = require("next-optimized-images");
const withPWA = require("next-pwa");

module.exports = withPlugins(
    [optimizedImages],
    [
      withPWA({
        pwa: {
          dest: "public",
        },
      }),
    ],
    {
      distDir: '../../dist/client',
    }
);
```

for absolute import(import Button from 'components/Button')

jsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": "client/"
    }
  }
```

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "dev:client": "nextjs src/client",
    "dev:server": "node src/server --out-dir dist/server --source-maps --watch",
    "dev": "dotenv -e .env.development yarn dev:client & yarn dev:server",
    "build": "yarn build:client && yarn build:server",
    "build:client": "dotenv -e .env.production next build src/client",
    "build:server": "node src/server --out-dir dist/server --source-maps",
    "build:staging": "yarn build:staging:client && yarn build:server",
    "build:staging:client": "dotenv -e .env.staging next build src/client",
    "start": "next start",
  },
```

.babelrc

```
{

    "plugins": [
      [
        "styled-components",
        {
          "ssr": true,
          "displayName": true,
          "preprocess": false
        }
      ]
    ],
    "presets": [
      "next/babel"
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the official NextJs documentation pages folder can be moved inside the src folder. But Config files like next.config.js and tsconfig.json should be inside the root directory, moving them to src won't work. Same goes for the public directory.

Move your next.config.js file to root folder.

Reference: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/src-directory

Comment: now I moved next.config.js and jsconfig.json outside of src folder i.e on root directory but still not working.

Comment: i am even pointing to src/client when running the server which you can see on my scripts

Comment: Is your pages folder inside client folder or src folder?

Comment: it is inside client folder.

Comment: It should be inside src folder. Pages folder should be a direct child of src folder.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get the same error on a Windows system where my pages folder was called "Pages" (capital P). Renaming it to lowercase P fixed it.