# gcloud, docker and nextjs: Couldn't find a `pages` directory

Tags: docker, next.js, gcloud

My config looks like this:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:current-alpine AS base
WORKDIR /base
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .

FROM base AS build
ENV NODE_ENV=production
WORKDIR /build
COPY --from=base /base ./
RUN npm run build

FROM node:current-alpine AS production
ENV NODE_ENV=production
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /build/package*.json ./
COPY --from=build /build/build ./build
COPY --from=build /build/public ./public
RUN npm install next

EXPOSE 3000
CMD npm run start
```

next.config.js

```
const withPWA = require('next-pwa');
const runtimeCaching = require('next-pwa/cache');

module.exports = withPWA({
  distDir: 'build',
  pwa: {
    dest: 'public',
    runtimeCaching,
  },
  experimental: {
    outputStandalone: true,
  },
  staticPageGenerationTimeout: 10000,
});
```

this works fine if I use `docker build -t [my project name] .` command, but fails with the `gcloud`. I'm using it like this `gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/my project name] --project my project name] --timeout=900s` but keep getting the error:

```
Error: > Couldn't find a `pages` directory. Please create one under the project root
```

Not sure what am I doing

Comment: You can check with the [documentation][https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/builds/submit] for the gcloud build command as I was not sure on your source file. Meanwhile you can refer to these [link1](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/builds/submit), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68117785/gcloud-builds-submit-command-is-not-working-as-per-the-documentation) and [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61903950/error-couldnt-find-a-pages-directory-please-create-one-under-the-project-roo).

Comment: Aparently, my Dockerfile was just ignored by the Cloud Build. I had to explicitly choose to use it, otherwise it used some default one

Comment: You can check with the [document](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/github/build-repos-from-github#console) in the configuration type if you choose Autodetected then automatically it detects cloudbuild.yaml or dockerfile or else you have to set default as dockerfile to use your docker.